# Is it possible to call web services like JSON parsing from Appdelegate method for "POST" in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to call web services like JSON parsing from AppDelegate.m class for "POST"?
I want to post data to server using web Service as application starts .

```
#pragma mark JSON Delegates

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [responseData  setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [responseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    responseData = nil;

}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *DictData = (NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue];




    }
```

Comment: please tell how I am trying to add web service in AppDelegate in json delegate it shows  No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'appendData:'

Comment: simple show your code man, i customize your self.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik this I included in AppDelegate.m

Comment: add connection method Name also plz..

Comment: `appendData` is not part of `NSData`, only `NSMutableData`.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I used @"POST" method

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks for help I used NSData instead of NSMutableData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I attach the sample method  add this in your **AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder   <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

NSURLConnection *clearSession;
NSMutableData * responseData;

}
```

in your **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 [self clearsession];  // this is your method Name
return YES;
}


-(void)clearsession

{
// call the clear session
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURLName.php"]];
// get the session ID and UserID from Sqlite

NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@",passyourString,nil];
NSMutableData *requestData =[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
clearSession = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[clearSession start];

}

#pragma mark - NSUrlConnectionDelegate Methods

-(void)connection:(NSConnection*)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
if (responseData == NULL)
{
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

[receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[responseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 UIAlertView *customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No NetWork" message:@"Interet Connection is Lost" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[customAlert show];


}




- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

   NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSString *str=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"result"];
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"success"])

    {
        // Add your Home Viewcontroller 

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
   UIViewController *viewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIDentifierName"];
   self.window.rootViewController=viewController;
    }
 else

  {
      // do ur stuff here 
   }


  }
```

**choice no-2**

use this [link](http://yorkstreetlabs.com/blog/call-web-service-as-ios-app-enters-the-background) , this is `protocol` method

Comment: if u need any assistance I hope with u

Answer (score 0):

You can. Check out AFNetworking as a good example to parse json data. I don't recommend you put parsing in app delegate. This delegate just handle things that is before root view controller get a chance to run.

Have you specify you follow the delegate protocol? Based on your code we cannot know.

Comment: what  delegate protocol I have to follow ?

Comment: can I call the web service through other view controller before application crashes ?

Comment: you need to check what json parsing library you are using, and check out the delegate protocol. Usually it is within a <>. You better to google some basic concepts what are protocol, delegate, and the view controller life cycle.